# Align an image with a hamburger menu

Tags: html, css, css-float, nav, hamburger-menu

I am trying to have an image and a hamburger menu aligned within the Header. And when clicked the list appears at the bottom of the image in a horizontal line.

But instead it lists vertical on the right of the image. How can I fix this? Should I but my list and img within different divs?

html

```
<header>
<img src="images/ace_in_the_hole.png" alt="Ace in the Hole Weekend Marathon Logo">
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#courseinfo">Course Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#register">Registration</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</li>
</ul>
</header>
```

css

```
img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: none;
}

header {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list*/
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: lightgray;}

/* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items. Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
    img{
        float: left;
        height: 5em;
    }
    ul.topnav li {display: none;} 
    ul.topnav li.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens  */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
    ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;  
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li:not(:last-child) {
        margin-top: 6em;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

javascript

```
 /* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when  the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
 } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
 }
 }
```

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't your actual code since the CSS wouldn't be read in this form. Just checking.

Comment: what does `myFunction()` do?

Comment: Hi. can you provide the js code your working with also

Comment: Yes sorry I got the code from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)  and I will add the js to my post.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was I added the image as the first li.

```
 <li><img src="images/ace_in_the_hole.png" alt="Ace in the Hole Weekend Marathon Logo"></li>
 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#courseinfo">Course Information</a></li>
 <li><a href="#register">Registration</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li class="icon">
```

Then in CSS I added the first child.

```
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
}
```

This way the image will show on the same line with the hambuger menu in mobile. But when you go to the desktop view, you will see the img as the header with the nav below.

Now my issue is making the nav horizontal in the mobile view, when the user clicks to see the hidden menu.